# How do I stop my FSUnit tests using F# full syntax

Tags: f#, fsunit

We are using the wonderful FSUnit for our unit testing.  This works fine, except the bodies of our tests insist on using full F# syntax (with 'in' at the end of each line etc.) instead of #light syntax.  For example:

```
module MyTests

open System
open NUnit.Framework
open FsUnit
open MyModule

[<TestFixture>] 
type ``Given a valid file`` () =

    let myFile = createSomeFile()

    [<Test>] member x.
     ``Processing the file succeeds`` () =
        let actual = processFile myFile in
        actual |> should be True
```

Note the 'in' at the end of the first line of the test.  Without that, the test won't compile - which is fine for short tests but is becoming a pain for longer test methods.  We've tried adding an explicit #light in the source but that seems to make no difference.  This is part of a large project with many modules, all of which - other than the test modules - are happily using light syntax (without any explicit #light).  What's triggering full syntax in the test modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a bit different indentation when writing members of the class. The following should be fine:

```
[<TestFixture>]  
type ``Given a valid file`` () = 
    let myFile = createSomeFile() 

    [<Test>] 
    member x.``Processing the file succeeds`` () = 
        let actual = processFile myFile
        actual |> should be True
```

The first problem is that the name of the member should be indented further than `.` and the second problem is that the body of the member should be indented further than the `member` keyword - in your version, the keyword is written after `[<Test>]` so it would work if you indented the body further.

Adding `in` solves the problem, because that's telling the compiler more explicitly how to interpret the code (and so it does not rely on indentation rules).

Aside - with some unit testing frameworks, it is also possible to use `module` which gives you a bit lighter syntax (but I'm not sure how that works if you need some initialization - i.e. to load a file):

```
[<TestFixture>]  
module ``Given a valid file`` = 
    let myFile = createSomeFile() 

    [<Test>] 
    let ``Processing the file succeeds`` () = 
        let actual = processFile myFile
        actual |> should be True
```

Comment: Thanks Tomas. A full, multiparagraph answer with formatting within 10 minutes of the question. :-)